# C# Input from TextBox to a new TextBox

Tags: c#

I am currently working with a Windows Form project and I am trying to make a TextBox allow input from another TextBox.  I have the following code below and am stuck trying to get this to function correctly.

```
namespace Arlistia3._0
{
    public partial class ArlistiaInterface : Form
    {
       public static string userInput;
       public ArlistiaInterface()
       {
         InitializeComponent();
         IntroScene();
       }

       private void IntroScene()
       {
        gameText.Text = "Welcome, what is your name?";
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

       private void playerTextInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           userInput = gameText.Text;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: playerTextInput_TextChanged...`gameText.Text = playerTextInput.Text`

Comment: Why are you assigning the `gameText.Text` inside the `playerTextInput_TextChanged` event?

Comment: gameText.Text = playerTextInput.Text is not what I am looking for unfortunately.

Comment: Can you specify which textboxes are you talking about?

Comment: What I am trying to do is make it to where when I type something in the playerText, it will show in gameText without clearing the screen.  Essentially above where it asks for the person's name, that should stay on the screen, the person should be able to type in playerText their name and then gameText will then say "Welcome" +player.

Comment: playerTextInput is the textbox where the player types in the various commands, etc throughout the program.  The gameText is the textBox where the program reflects the info throughout the length of the program

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. It's similar to Lei Yang's:

```
private void playerTextInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gameText.Text = "Welcome, " + playerTextInput.Text;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It helps but I do not need the gameText to change in the info on the screen.  So "Welcome, what is your name?" should also remain on the screen. When I am typing the name out, it automatically rewrites what is in the gameText.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
string Welcom="Welcome, what is your name?";
private void playerTextInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gameText.Text = Welcom + playerTextInput.Text;
}
```

Comment: Kind of what I want but still not exactly.

Comment: For instance, here is a link to what I am looking for.

Comment: @Christian Kirby 
How about using two TextBox?  textbox1.text="Welcome, what is your name?"; //fixed  textbox2.text= player //playerTextInput.Text;

Comment: I'm sorry, can you break that down differently?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. You may need to set the Multiline property of your gameText TextBox to true, I'm not sure.

```
   private void playerTextInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       gameText.Text += "You: " + playerTextInput.Text + Environment.Newline;
   }
```